# Uploading R objects to Azure Blob Containers

Tags: r, azure, dataframe, azure-storage

I want to upload an R object to a Azure container.

I am able to do so after I store/write the data frame in a csv file in a local folder. This can be done from the R environment.

I want to upload the data frame as a csv directly from the R environment.

I am using AzureStor package.

Comment: A csv is not an "R object"

Comment: Looking at the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html, if you don't specify path then you get string back containing CSV data from this method. Can't you upload that string directly in storage?

Comment: @GauravMantri OP is using R, not python

Comment: @GauravMantri I have solved it. Please see my answer

Comment: @HongOoi I have solved it. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution

```
 w_con <- textConnection("foo", "w")
 write.csv(ds,w_con)
 r_con <- textConnection(textConnectionValue(w_con))
 close(w_con)
 upload_blob(cont_output, src=r_con, dest=paste0("check_",ds[1, "Claim Number"], 
                                                   '_',ds[1, "Claim Type"], ".csv"))
 close(r_con)
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is to write out the df to a temporary file, and upload that. You can wrap this into a function if you want a self-contained solution.

```r
upload_csv <- function(df, name=deparse(substitute(df)), container)
{
    f <- tempfile()
    write.csv(df, f)
    on.exit(unlink(f))
    storage_upload(container, f, name)
}

upload_csv(mydf, "df.csv", mycontainer)
```

Trust me, this is easier than working with a connection.

Comment: OP doesn’t want to write to a local file.

Comment: @GauravMantri i know, but it's the simplest solution nonetheless. You can write to a connection and upload that, but that just complicates things for no reason